# json parse issue in the same folder

Tags: jquery, json

i would like to parse a JSON file and here is what i have done :

```
 var producteur = $.parseJSON(lot.json);
```

i have done something like you told me :

```
 var recuperation = $.getJSON("lots.json", function(json){ var parsing = $.parseJSON(recuperation);
```

the first part is working : the getJson but the $.Parse json won't work do you see whythanks.

Comment: @adeneo: He actually wants an AJAX request to read the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to retrieve the file first.

`$.parseJSON` only parses a JSON string to javascript object. Use `$.getJSON` to make the request to retrieve it.

Use :

```
$.getJSON('lot.json', function( response){    
   /* do something with response here. 
      It is a javascript object/array already converted by jQuery*/
})
```

Comment: i have done something like you told me : var recuperation = $.getJSON("lots.json", function(json){
  var parsing = $.parseJSON(recuperation);                   the first part is working : the getJson but the $.Parse json won't work do you see why

Comment: you don't have to parse it, and your data in my answer will be `response` or in your code `json`. Please read the docs in jQuery API. There are examples also there